# Make debugger stop at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException

Tags: .net, debugging, exception

I want to make the debugger in Visual Studio 2010 stop at the exception `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException`.

I use Debugging -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

When I drill down I would expect to see `System.Data.Services` entry, but that's not the case.

How should I mark the exception for stopping, if I can't find it in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although that particular exception is not present you can add it using the `Add` button in the Exceptions dialog.

On the add dialog box select Common Language Runtime Exceptions and use the full name of the exception `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException`. After tick the Thrown checkbox and the debugger should break when it's thrown.

Comment: +1 I was about to answer the same :) Official link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4t258c.aspx